# Does Redis Windows fork use less RAM because is using memory-mapped files?

Tags: linux, windows, memory, redis, memory-mapped-files

I found the following forum post in Redis Google Group: [Verify Redis on Windows memory consumption](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/redis-db/neJEsXOSDhE), and some Microsoft Open Tech team member states:

> In order to implement persistence and simulate the fork()
>   copy-on-write mechanism, the Windows port of Redis places the Redis
>   heap in a memory mapped file that can be shared with child processes.
>   Data is definitely stored in memory but because of the memory-mapped
>   file working set will be accounted for under "shared working set"
>   instead of "private working set". You can inspect the shared working
>   set of redis-server.exe using task manager or Windows Performance
>   Monitor. You should see values that much closer reflect
>   "used_memory_human"

Why I'm asking this question? Because I found that `redis-server` process takes significant less memory than what `info` command says (for example, `info` shows that Redis is using 148MB while *shared working set* in task manager shows 48MB).

Since the MSOpenTech member says that Redis for Windows is using memory-mapped files, **does this means that Redis on Windows uses less RAM than Linux version?**.

Comment: no. the note's just saying that ram usage is accounted for differently in windows than it is in linux.

Comment: @MarcB Yeah, but memory mapped files are mapped to virtual memory, so maybe not all memory is in RAM but in disk.

Comment: there's be no point memmapping a file into virtual memory... that'd be using disk, where the file is ALREADY stored.

Comment: @MarcB Are you sure? For example, Wikipedia article about MMP states: **A memory-mapped file is a segment of virtual memory which has been assigned a direct byte-for-byte correlation with some portion of a file or file-like resource.**

Comment: memmapping assigns the file's contents to a physical location in ram, which may not necessary correspond to actual physical ram, so yeah, as such it'd be "virtual". but "virtual memory" is extra "ram space" created by using disk space

Comment: @MarcB My question is why working set and what info says are different values. It seems like it's not mapping the entire data to the RAM, am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

For those of you coming to this question later 2016's, open Process Hacker (process explorer) and look/add column `Working Set` .

The memory usage shown there is related to what's Redis actually using.